# How to handle this wordpress custom post type rewrite problem?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

i have a custom post type called "carrier", this cpt has a custom taxonomy called "carrier-category".
the cpt has the following rewrite: `'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'carrier/%category%']`
the taxonomy has this rewrite: `'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'carrier-category', 'with_front' => false]`

to replace the `%category%` i rewrite it with this function:

```
public function rewriteLink($post_link, $id = 0) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ( is_object( $post ) && is_singular('carrier') ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'carrier-categories' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

so that i get a permalink like "localhost/carrier/professionals/xyz" for a post in my cpt.

i need now to add a normal page with this structure: `localhost/carrier/about-company`
but if i add a page as child from the page "carrier" i wil get 404.
how to fix my rewrite, or is it a other problem?

Comment: You're right. WordPress simply won't be able to discern between a page and a category. Would a better solution be having your post type simply as `carrier` and your taxonomy as `carrier/category` (instead of `carrier-category`)? This will give you almost what you want, but WordPress will be able to discern categories using the `category` static string "divider".

Comment: than i cant use gutenberg on the category pages....i switcht from one cpt + taxonomy to 2 cpts without taxonomy...thats in my case better and i dont block urls on the level that i need